# Should you delete unanswered questions that you no longer need the answer to?

Tags: discussion

I believe that you can delete a question that you post, so long as no one has answered it.  However, people may have commented on it, favorited it, or voted on it.
If you realize that you no longer need the answer to the question (say it was for a project you're no longer working on, or that you formulated to problem incorrectly to begin with)... is it better for the community to delete it, so as to not waste anyone's time or detract from people who really need answers... or is that actually more rude, to take something down that others may have thought was interesting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it offers *any* value to the community it should be left up. If it is ill-posed for some reason, it would benefit the community to edit the question (and answer it yourself if possible). I would think in some situations it is ok to leave it ill-posed and then answer it yourself, saying in the answer what was wrong with the original question.

I would take upvotes, favorites, views and comments as evidence that it is a noteworthy subject that is of interest to multiple parties. If it is misleading for some reason, the community should take action (in the form of comments or answers) to prevent misguided questions or answers for future viewers of the topic.

Comment: +1 You got there 9 seconds before I did :-).

Answer (score 9):

As soon as someone provides an answer, comment, edit, or vote, the question has become the work of the community.  Poorly posed questions--non-questions--should be closed as such, and usually will be (by high-rep community members and/or moderators).  There's a gray area, such as the incorrect formulation you refer to, but in general any well-posed question that has generated non-trivial community interaction ought not to be closed without public discussion.

Comment: oh, I just hovered over the "delete" button and realized that it is a "vote to delete" button, not a straight-up delete.

Comment: remember that owners *can't* delete questions once they have at least one answer with at least one upvote.

Comment: @JandR: "Voting to delete" your own post will delete it without requiring votes from anyone else.